# FRP bypass on droid turbo lolipop 5.1 build su4tl-49

Tags: motorola-droid

on build SU4TL-44 the method works but not on this build 49. You can tap build# all day with nothing happening. I can search google and goto rootjunky but cant download. I can goto play store but cant install any apps. Any other suggestions. My bootloader is locked and I cant bypass FRP.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not responding to the Build being tapped, I'd cruise on over to Settings 》Accessability 》Magnification Gestures. If that is turned on, that could very well be your problem as it interferes with correctly detecting how many taps you've done.

If you're wanting to access D.O. solely for USB Debugging, Magnification Gestures isn't turned on, and tapping Build still isn't working then try:

- Navigate to Settings 》Applications and look for the option called "Development". If you see it, enable it
- Under Development, look for USB Debugging; it may not be enabled

Also check out:

- Settings 》Wireless and Network 》USB Settings

  - Tick the option "Ask on Connection"
- Navigate back to Settings 》Application 》Development and verify that the USB Debugging option is enabled

As far as unlocking your boot loader, simply use the ADB/Fastboot commands in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the boot loader unlocked. Used sunshine. Then installed king root. Both a success. Still cant get passed frp to do a factory reset. I dont have an applications setting nor development. Dont have wireless and network setting either. Still cant access developer options by tapping build number. Ive read that this build is a pain in the butt to get passed. Would love to put the stock rom or a CM rom on this phone. But no way to enable usb debugging and that sux.

Comment: And also Google told me to contact Moto and send it to them to re-flash it. Well how can they get passed FRP and enable usb debugging to re-flash it? Moto said send it in for repair and we will fix it. Really, then why cant I? What do they know that nobody else has figured out..very puzzling